# Trouble using Microsoft.Graph with Azure Automation Runbooks

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm working on integrating Microsoft.Graph functionality in Azure Automation Runbooks with Powershell, but I keep encountering an error when trying to connect to Microsoft.Graph in the runbook itself. Here's the code in the runbook:

`Connect-MgGraph -ClientID "<clientid>" -TenantID "<tenantid>" -CertificateThumbprint "<thumbprint>"`

This code works in Azure CLI and through PowerShell ISE connected to our Azure instance, but when it's run in the Automation Runbook it can't connect to Microsoft.Graph and shows an error that says:

"A socket operation encountered a dead network."

The network is up and running, we are able to connect to ExchangeOnline with no issue. Has anyone seen this before or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Could this be of use?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661009/port-8999-is-taken-with-exception-a-socket-operati?orderBy=Newest). Could you be using Connect-MgGraph multiple times? If you just run that one section of code in it's own runbook with no other command, does the same issue occur?

Comment: Yes, still runs into the socket operation error

Answer (score 0):

I created one azure Ad service principal with certificate authentication and added Microsoft Graph permissions to the Azure AD App like below:-

[image]

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=DaemonConsoleCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
```

[image]

Got connected to Mg-graph with local Powershell like below:-

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId "xxxxxxxx-5254-45b5-b838-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -TenantId "xxxxxxx-7f45-4ce4-99ed-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx198c14f9118189b6362"
```

[image]

Now Tried connecting to Mg-graph in Azure automation like below:-

I created one Automation runbook with Powershell 5.1 version like below:-

[image]

Installed Microsoft.Graph.Authentication for Powershell 5.1 module in Azure automation account like below:-

*Select your Azure automation account > Modules > Add Module > Browse in gallery > Microsoft.Graph.Authentication > Import the module*

[image]

[image]

Click Import and the module will be imported like below:-

[image]

Used the below command to Connect to Microsoft Graph:-

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId "xxxxxxxx-5254-45b5-b838-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -TenantId "xxxxxxx-7f45-4ce4-99ed-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx198c14f9118189b6362"
```

[image]

Output:-

[image]

When I did not import the module and ran the command multiple times, Even I got a dead socket network error like you, refer below:-

[image]

Comment: The code on the screenshots is too small and unreadable. Could you please insert the code with PS commands from the second and third screenshot? It would be easier for the author of the question copy&paste the command and try it.

Comment: @user2250152 Thank you for your input, I changed the answer according to your recommendation. Can you check now?

Comment: Looks better now